# styling a padlet embed iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, widget, embed, styling

hide/add styling inside Padlet embed iframe with jQuery, won't target div#surface-header.app-bar.surface-header

Padlet iframe Embed Code Demo:

```
<iframe src="https://padlet.com/embed/s0ckmpcp5oauwa0z" frameborder="0" allow="camera;microphone;geolocation" style="width:100%;height:608px;display:block;padding:0;margin:0"> 
    </iframe>
```

Padlet full Embed Code Demo:

```
<div class="padlet-embed" style="border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius:2px;box-sizing:border-box;overflow:hidden;position:relative;width:100%;background:#F4F4F4"><p style="padding:0;margin:0"><iframe src="https://padlet.com/embed/s0ckmpcp5oauwa0z" frameborder="0" allow="camera;microphone;geolocation" style="width:100%;height:608px;display:block;padding:0;margin:0"></iframe></p><div style="padding:8px;text-align:right;margin:0;"><a href="https://padlet.com?ref=embed" style="padding:0;margin:0;border:none;display:block;line-height:1;height:16px" target="_blank"><img src="https://resources.padletcdn.com/assets/made_with_padlet.png" width="86" height="16" style="padding:0;margin:0;background:none;border:none;display:inline;box-shadow:none" alt="Made with Padlet"></a></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter any styling inside an iframe, unless:

1) You own the origin of the iframe

2) Your site lives at `iframe-origin.com/mysite`

3) Iframe allows you to insert a script in the page that contains your embedded content

4) Your site is allowed to communicate with `iframe.com` following CORS specifications, which is sharing data via `postMessage` API.

All the above are pretty uncommon. The most common way is usually via limited exposed APIs that allow you to customise specific bits of the rendered iframe.